# Чем отличается встроенная функция С++ от макроса Си?

Tags: c++, c, компиляция, препроцессор

Как я понял, встроенная функция в С++ это аналог макроса Си. Но в книге прочел, что встраиванием кода встроенной функции занимается компилятор, в то время как в Си макросы встраиваются препроцессором. Также макросы могут быть только однострочными, в то время, как встроенные функции впринципе не ограничены в размерах (хотя рекомедуется не делать встроееными функции более 2 строк кода длинной). Подозреваю это не все важные отличия.

Comment: Не забывайте, что в C++ есть те же самые макросы, что в C. Резонно предположить, что встроенные функции были добавлены не просто так. Макросы, кстати, вполне можно делать многострочными (визуально).

Comment: В Си тоже есть inline-функции. Вообще, ключевое слово inline - это всего лишь подсказка компилятору. А отличия в том, что макрос разворачивается в код на стадии препроцессинга. В случае с inline-функции - компилятор, по возможности, вставляет машинный код функции вместо его вызова (командой процессора call, или аналогичной, в зависимости от архитектуры).

Comment: функции можно перегружать, например

Answer (score 3):

Важное отличие макроса от `inline` (это скорее нужно перевести, как встраиваемая, а не встроенная) функции тем, что макрос отрабатывает на этапе препроцессинга. Раньше препроцессингом занимался отдельный процесс, сейчас компилятор обычно делает его сам. Но! на этапе препроцессинга есть только токены (грубо говоря, отдельные слова), но нет ни типов, ни переменных ни функций, ни блоков кода (то есть, правила видимости функций и переменных для макросов не работают - макрос доступен от точки объявлений и до конца файла или отмены макроса). Проверка корректности того, что получилось будет производиться только при компиляции. Поэтому возможны различные "чудеса". Например, классика (*эта функция специально написана без скобок, но и они тут не помогут сильно*)

```
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
```

И вызываем так

```
max(x+1, b++)
```

и дальше  будет не совсем то, что ожидается.

Если же использовать inline функцию, то поведение будет очень предсказуемым.

В целом, компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные и сами умеют хорошо инлайнить, когда это уместно. Поэтому, в большинстве случаев это ключевое слово даже и не нужно.

> Также макросы могут быть только однострочными

макросы могут быть столь угодно большими. обратный слеш в конце строки поможет в этом (главное, что бы после него не было пробелов или других символов кроме перевода строк).

Важно также то, что переменные, объявленные внутри `inline` живут до конца функции (или блока кода), а переменные, объявленные внутри макроса могут живут в вызывающей их функции. Из за этого возможны конфликты имен.

В целом, макросы и `inline` функции хоть и могут делать похожие вещи, это все таки достаточно разные инструменты. Макросы умеют такое, что inline функции никогда не смогут (классический пример - [X макрос](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)).

Comment: #define max(a,b) a>b?a:b такие макросы рекомендуется всегда объявлять как #define max(a,b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b) заключая каждый параметр в скобки.

Comment: конечно. Я же специально привел для примера. Хотя, даже если скобки добавить, лучше не станет (там ещё куча остается багов)

Comment: Не будет никаких багов, если изначально понимать, что всё это обрабатывается сугубо на уровне текста кода.

Comment: если понимать, что там будет, то конечно не будет "никаких багов". Вот только к примеру,  многие не ожидают, что переменная может быть инкрементированна дважды.

Answer (score 2):

> Также макросы могут быть только однострочными

Это полуправда, ведь никто не мешает поставить обратный слэш (" \ ") и писать с новой строки, будто она - продолжение предыдущей

> в то время, как встроенные функции впринципе не ограничены в размерах

Чем длиннее функция, тем меньше вероятность, что ее заинлайнит компилятор. Но, понятное дело, что компилятор не на строки ориентируется, а на операторы (с учетом оптимизации).

В общем случае стоит противопоставлять не просто inline-функции (ведь для современных компиляторов само ключевое слово `inline` - это не приказ и даже не рекомендация что-то там встраивать), а `constexpr`. У них, как (как и у глобальных констант, вместо #define-констант) есть ряд преимуществ:

- Они более типобезопасны
- Они учитывают области видимости
- Более читаемый и предсказуемый результат благодаря тому, что аргументы вычисляются, а не подставляются

Конечно же за счет этого строгого контроля inline-функции не заменят макросы в некоторых аспектах (условная компиляция, какая-то часть кодогенерации), но в остальных - стоит отдавать им предпочтение.